# Calling multiple array function from server side but not getting called

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vb.net

i am Calling  multiple array function from server side but not getting called
taking colvalue,rowvalue,Category,Property1 as array assigning value in it from loop through db then calling QfdAjaxBind function but not able to call it

```
Protected Sub bindqfdmat(requestid As String)
 Dim colvalue(50) As String
        Dim rowvalue(50) As String
        Dim Category(50) As String
        Dim Property1(50) As String
qryNpdQfdTime = "Select MTX_CUST_REQ,MTX_TEST_PARA,MTX_CATEGORY,MTX_PROPERTY,MTX_STATUS,"
        qryNpdQfdTime += "MTX_CRT_BY,MTX_CRT_DT "
       qryNpdQfdTime += "from t_apqp_matrix where MTX_NPD_NO='" & requestid.Trim() & "'"
Dim dtcustapp As New DataTable
        dtcustapp = getdata(qryNpdQfdTime)
If dtcustapp.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For j As Integer = 0 To dtcustapp.Rows.Count - 1
                    colvalue(j) = dtcustapp.Rows(j)("MTX_CUST_REQ").ToString()
                    rowvalue(j) = dtcustapp.Rows(j)("MTX_TEST_PARA").ToString()
                    Category(j) = dtcustapp.Rows(j)("MTX_CATEGORY").ToString()
                    Property1(j) = dtcustapp.Rows(j)("MTX_PROPERTY").ToString()
                Next
            End If
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(UI.Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), String.Format("QfdAjaxBind({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});", colvalue, rowvalue, Category, Property1), True)
 End Sub
```

client side

```
function QfdAjaxBind(colvalue, rowvalue, Category, Property1) {
}
```

what should be correct syntax or where it is missing any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Your client-side function doesn't do anything, maybe that's the problem

Comment: @JeremyThille  i have written something inside it  not mentioned here but the function QfdAjaxBind is not getting called that is the issue

Comment: Ah, well, providing an empty function doesn't really help solve the problem, does it :) What's the actual relevant code then? What's _not_ calling QfdAjaxBind?

Comment: @JeremyThille is the syntax is correct function QfdAjaxBind(colvalue, rowvalue, Category, Property1) {
}

Comment: This is just a function declaration, yes it is correct. If it wasn't, your console would complain and throw a syntax error, it would tell you

Comment: Make sure to puts quotes where parameter is a string  as javascript doesn’t recognize your paramters as a string, so the code becomes QfdAjaxBind(‘{0}’, {1}, {2}, {3});…… if paramter 0 is a string